# Writing a very large CSV file From DB output in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a DB of sensor data that is being collected every second. The client would like to be able to download 12hour chunks in CSV format - This is all done.

The output is sadly not straight data and needs to be processed before the CSV can be created (parts are stored as JSON in the DB) - so I cant just dump the table.

So, to reduce load, I figured that the first time the file is downloaded, I would cache it to disk, then any more requests just download that file.

If I dont try to write it (using file_put_contents, FILE_APPEND), and just echo every line it is fine, but writing it, even if I give the script 512M it runs out of memory.

**so this works**

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    //processing code
    $content = //CSV formatting
    echo $content;
}
```

**This does not**

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    //processing code
    $content = //CSV formatting
    file_put_contents($pathToFile, $content, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

It seems like even thought I am calling file_put_contents at every line, it is storing it all to memory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using fwrite() to write it line by line instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that file_put_contents is trying to dump the entire thing at once. Instead you should loop through in your formatting and use fopen, fwrite, fclose.

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    //processing code
    $content[] = //CSV formatting
    $file = fopen($pathToFile, a);
    foreach($content as $line)
    {
        fwrite($file, $line);
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

This will limit the amount of data trying to be tossed around in data at any given time.

Comment: While essentially correct notice how in the original uses `echo $content` so it's just `$content = // CSV formatting ; fwrite($file, $content);` and move the `fopen` and `fclose` out of the main loop.

Comment: Are you sure opening and closing the file all the time is really necessary? Otherwise I agree, try writing to the file on line at a time using fwrite.

Comment: Race conditions anyone? What if a second user loads this while another is still waiting for it to load? I imagine data corruption would be possible, and even likely since in an office environment users might all head to look at such a thing at the same time.

Comment: @sakatc Then I'd cache the file, so if there is a file not older than X, serve that file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree completely with writing one line at a time, you will never have memory issues this way since there is never more than 1 line loaded in to memory at a time. I have an application that does the same. A problem I have found with this method however, is that the file takes forever to finish writing. So this post is to back up what has already been said, but also to ask all of you for an opinion on how to speed this up? For example, my system cleans a data file against a suppression file, so I read in one line at a time and look for a match in the suppression file, then if no match is found, I write the line in to the new cleaned file. A 50k line file is taking about 4 hours to finish however, so I am hoping to find a better way. I have tried this several ways, and at this point I load the entire suppression file in to memory now to avoid my main reading loop to have to run another loop through each line in the suppression file, but even that is still taking hours.

So, line by line is by far the best way to manage your system's memory, but I'd like to get the processing time for a 50k line file (lines are email addresses and first and last names) to finishing running in less than 30 minutes if possible.

fyi: the suppression file is 16,000 kb in size and total memory used by the script as told by memory_get_usage() is about 35 megs.

Thanks!