# Writing large CSV file from PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, csv, pdo

First of, there is already a question with the same title ([Writing a very large CSV file From DB output in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021230/writing-a-very-large-csv-file-from-db-output-in-php)), though dealing with a separate issue (improper use of `file_put_contents`).

I am processing an unbuffered PDO prepared statement, doing this row by row, and writing the output to a file. However, for whatever reason PHP is spawning more than 500M of memory. Regardless of how big the dataset is, I don't expect PHP to use nothing as much.

```
<?php
$format = [
    'name' => function ($e) { return $e }
];

$sth = $db
    ->prepare("[..]");

$db
    ->execute([], [\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false]); // This is incorrect. $driver_options is a parameter of `prepare` method.


$output_file = tempnam('/tmp', 'mama-report-');

$fp = fopen($output_file, 'wb');

while ($row = $this->stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { # line 49 (see comments)
    foreach ($format as $name => $f) {
        if (isset($row[$name])) {
            $row[$name] = $f($row[$name]);
        }
    }

    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}

fclose($fp);
```

How to I write a processed output of the prepared statement to CSV?

Comment: Why do not use `SELECT INTO`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html ?

Comment: I can't use `SELECT INTO` because 1. the data is coming from a cluster (different FS), 2. it needs to be post-processed.

Comment: When asking a question, do not *retell* the error message. But bring it whole and untouched. And indicate the row where the error occurred. Thanks.

Comment: If this somehow helps you, "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 524288000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /[..]/report.class.php on line 49" Line 49 indicated in the code example above.

Comment: Ok, let's do some basic debugging. Does it work with empty loop? On which iteration it stops? How much memory does every iteration consume? Does your whatever wrapper indeed understand the setting?

Comment: `execute()` from your class on github doesn't support additional option parameter. Did you added it since?

Comment: `$driver_options` is altogether a `prepare` parameter.

Comment: Well, to blame PDO for eating up your memory, test it with *PDO*, not some wrapper. In it's current form the question is obviously too localized.

Comment: @YourCommonSense the latter is not the main issue. In fact, PHP is able to dump the whole array (nonetheless, thanks for pointing out). The thing that seemingly causes memory exceeding is `fputcsv`. If I comment out `fputcsv` then the whole loop finishes successfully.

Comment: No, that's not true. Still looking into it.

Comment: there are **two** statements in this line, fputcsv  *and* array_values(). It seems you are inclined to fancy syntax sugar. Try to make your code less modern-looking but more explicit and robust.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, well now I am really confused. I've stripped down the test to a basic CLI script without any fancy wrappers, https://gist.github.com/gajus/934eedb6959bc3a47d93. Still an error.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It seems like it is a PHP PDO implementation bug. `prepare` is ignoring `$driver_options`. This worked fine, https://gist.github.com/gajus/ab6bcd59ba7fdf06a1de.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your implementation I have a feeling that set of PDOStatement's `$driver_options` is different from PDO object's set of options. It is unclear from documentation, but [the note on manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prpdo%20statementepare.php) looks somewhat suspicious to me. It seems it accepts only options that affect statement only, not the whole connection.

So, I would set an option usual way, like you did:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, 0);
```