# Getting might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address

Tags: php

I am getting the below error when we are hitting a php page which is getting records from mysql database and inserting in a csv .The count is very large around 3,400,000 when we have less data then no issue is coming .please guide what can we do for this issue.

Error :search_fiter.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Comment: When receiving temporarily down message can you connect to the machine? Is anything in the logs? Is the database up? We need more details to be able to assist.

Comment: Yes we can, nothing in logs, yes db us up

Comment: Are queries executing on DB during downtime? Are connections at DB or server level pooling up?

Comment: Yes queries are getting executed using command prompt

Answer (score -1):

is your page timing out? php often has a limit on how long a page request can last, which you can change in the specific page with php's inbuilt function `set_time_limit(seconds)`. though there may be other configurations on the server that also limit max request times.

Comment: I have set this to 120

Comment: What are other configurations in server and what can I try next

Comment: The error message indicates that php was not even called!

Comment: What can I do to rectify

Comment: @shadow the message is from chrome, not the server.  they say this request works fine if there are fewer records. leads me to believe this is a timeout issue, or possibly memory. nothing to indicate php was "not called" however.

Comment: Yes true because when we have less records say 200000 all are getting inserted to CSV

Comment: @NS009 have you tried another browser? this may be a case where chrome is cancelling the session because it hasn't heard anything from the server now that I think about it. you could try sending regular pings to the browser, like space characters, throughout the insertion process, to see if that helps prevent it from cancelling. i only suggest this, because I am seeing that this message seems to be specific to chrome when searching google.

Comment: @NS009 also, is two minutes enough to instert 3.4 million records? how long does the 2 million record request take?

Comment: Let me try  other browser like mozila

Comment: @dqhendricks it wil take 3-5 minutes to select the records and then insert

Comment: @NS009 then you may need to set_time_limit(seconds) to a much higher number. 120 only allows two minutes then cancels the request.

Comment: But I am getting this Error in less than 2 minutes

Comment: @NS009 I see. What happens in other browser? the php time limit only includes DB/system calls if it's a windows server, otherwise it only counts actual script running time by the way.

Comment: @NS009 also, you definitely should check the error logs. there might be better clues there.

Comment: Same error in edge what can I do next

Comment: @NS009 check the php and server error logs.

Comment: @dqhendricks if php ran into timeout or memory issue, then there wiuld be a php error message displayed, not a chrome one.

Comment: @Shadow not always: https://serverfault.com/questions/183708/what-happens-when-apache-times-out

Comment: @dqhendricks apache timeout is not the same as php timeout and apache does send a proper http error code.

Comment: @Shadow but the message in the browser is unclear. the link i sent you is a curl timeout that was running in a PHP page. OP seems to be executing these query via command prompt through their PHP page, so whatever is happening could be on the apache side.

Comment: I checked logs it was saying memory exhausted I increased to 812 still same issue

Comment: @Shadow this appears to be a memory issue as OP has discovered...

Comment: What can I do for this

Comment: @NS009 we would need to see the PHP code then to help. are you loading a bunch of db records into active memory, then putting them into the database after processing? could you batch this process on a loop, unsetting and releasing any stored records, doing only X number of records at a time?

Comment: Actually records are very large 3500000 and inserting in CSV file

Comment: @NS009 would need to know how you are storing the database data, and how you are writing it to file. check out this question. it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021230/writing-a-very-large-csv-file-from-db-output-in-php

Comment: @dqhendricks a memory issue does not mean it is a php one - you would get a php memory error in that case.

Comment: @Shadow either way, it was a memory issue, which was one of my theories that you said couldn't be a possibility.

Comment: @dqhendricks no, you wrote it was a php issue. That's what I challenged!

Comment: @Shadow i said "they say this request works fine if there are fewer records. leads me to believe this is a timeout issue, or possibly memory. nothing to indicate php was "not called" however."